# Как найти элемент в массиве по key value и поставить его на первое место в vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как можно найти элемент у которого статус `isNew == true` и поставить его на первое место в списке?

```js
data() {
  return {
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        isNew: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        isNew: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        isNew: true
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items">{{item.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать средствами `JS`:

```js
let items = [
     {id: 1, isNew: false},
     {id: 2, isNew: false},
     {id: 3, isNew: true},
];
console.log(`До:`, items);
let needle_index = items.findIndex(item=>item.isNew);
let needle = items[needle_index];
if(!!needle){
 items.splice(needle_index,1);
 items.unshift(needle);
}
console.log(`После:`, items);
```

Comment: у меня почему то первый элемент становиться undefind, я поместил это условие в computed, у меня сейчас нет true не одного элемента, возможно из за этого

Comment: Да, надо проверку сделать для этого, если не находит индекс то возвращает -1, и конечно же в массиве нет такого индекса. Поправил код

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения, если объектов с `isNew: true` может быть несколько.

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    isNew: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isNew: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    isNew: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    isNew: true
  },
];
console.log(`До:`, items);
const sorted = items.sort((a, b) => a.isNew && b.isNew ? (a.id < b.id ? 1 : -1) : -1);
console.log(`После: `, sorted);
```